# Authlogic Webapp does not work any more in selenium-Javascript tests

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara, authlogic

Testing a Ruby on Rails application, I have working tests (also asa logged in user), however as soon as I put the "`:js=>true`" option behind a test

```
it "does", :js => true do
    activate_authlogic 
    visit '/'
end
```

a get the web page with an internal error back

```
 You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects
```

How can I get this to work? How can I determine the error more closely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now it works for me, I think because of this dirty snippet

```
    module Authlogic
        module Session
          module Activation
            module ClassMethods
              def controller
                if !Thread.current[:authlogic_controller]
                  Thread.current[:authlogic_controller] = Authlogic::TestCase::MockController.new
                end
              Thread.current[:authlogic_controller]
            end
          end
        end
      end
     end
```

witch comes from the question [SO: authlogic-with-capybara-cucumber-selenium-driver-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775472/authlogic-with-capybara-cucumber-selenium-driver-not-working/12378166#12378166)