# Authlogic / Selenium breaks after rails 3.2.12 upgrade

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authlogic, rspec-rails

I'm using Authlogic and having difficulty getting my Selenium tests to work with **:js=>true** after upgrading to   Rails 3.2.12.  The same tests use to worked under Rails 3.1.3.  I am running my tests using Spork.

I am logging in through Selenium launches Firefox (19.0.2), fills the login form but then I get a permissions error from Authlogic, the standard **"You are not allowed to access this action."**

I can see that many people are having issues with this but as I mentioned, has only became a problem for me once upgrading from Rails 3.1.3 to Rails 3.2.12.  I suspect that the issue may be within my spec_helper file (below) and in particularly  within the

> module Authlogic

block which I got from here:

[Authlogic with Capybara + Cucumber + Selenium Driver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775472/authlogic-with-capybara-cucumber-selenium-driver-not-working/12378166#12378166)

```
**spec_helper.rb**

require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
require 'authlogic/test_case' 

include Authlogic::TestCase

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

  require 'rspec/rails'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    config.color_enabled = true

    ApplicationController.skip_before_filter :activate_authlogic
    config.before(:each, :type => :request) do
      activate_authlogic
    end

    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

    config.include Capybara::DSL

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end

    config.before(:each, :js => true) do
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium

      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

      module Authlogic
          module Session
            module Activation
              module ClassMethods
                def controller
                  if !Thread.current[:authlogic_controller]
                    Thread.current[:authlogic_controller] = Authlogic::TestCase::MockController.new
                  end
                Thread.current[:authlogic_controller]
              end
            end
          end
        end
       end
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.include(MailerMacros)
    config.before(:each) { reset_email }

    config.mock_with :mocha

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.order = "random"

    config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
    config.filter_run :focus => true
    config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

My understanding is that Authlogic and Selenium Webdriver work on different threads hence the need for this patch in the spec_helper file.

In the Request Spec I get a permissions error from Authlogic.  Here is the Request Spec test in question:

```
# UNIT REQUEST SPEC
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Units" do

  describe "GET /admin/units/new" do
    before(:each) do
      activate_authlogic
      UserSession.create FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user, :email => "foo@bar.com", :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password")      

      visit root_path
      fill_in "user_session[email]", :with => "foo@bar.com"
      fill_in "user_session[password]", :with => "password" 
      click_button "Sign In"    
    end

    it "displays a pop up dialog after unit is created", :focus, :js => true do
      visit new_admin_unit_path
      fill_in "Title", :with => "Unit Title"
      fill_in "Code", :with => "U-TEST"
      fill_in "Learning Outcome", :with => "Some Learning Outcome"
      fill_in "unit[learning_outcomes_attributes][0][assessment_methods_attributes][0][content]", :with => "Some Assessment Criteria"

      click_button "Save and Publish"      
      page.should have_css('div.ui-dialog')
    end
  end
end
```

My Capybara tests are working ok with:

```
activate_authlogic
UserSession.create FactoryGirl.build(:user)
```

in the before(:each) block, the problem only arises when using :js=>true

So, my questions are:

- Is it a case that with Rails 3.2.x that the spec_helper fix (module Authlogic ... ) no longer works.
- If that is in fact the case, what is the "normal" way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just revisited this today.  When I upgraded Rails I also upgraded capybara to the latest version (2.1.0).  It seems that downgrading capybara from this version (2.1.0) to version 2.0.1 seemed to do the trick.  I can see that capybara (2.0.1) uses xpath (1.0.0) while capybara (2.1.0) uses xpath (2.0.0) along with a different version of nokogiri gem.  I have no idea if there is a link there but here is my gem file if anyone cares to take a look:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

gem 'rack-mini-profiler'        
gem 'authlogic'                 
gem 'rails3-generators'   
gem 'mysql2'  
gem 'declarative_authorization' 
gem 'kaminari'                  
gem "foreigner"                
gem 'validates_timeliness'     
gem "activerecord-import", ">= 0.2.0"
gem 'ezcrypto'                 
gem 'thin'                       
gem 'exception_notification'    
gem 'mail'
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8.0'
gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'
gem 'jasmine', :group => [:development, :test]  
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'tinymce-rails'             
gem 'acts_as_list'              
gem 'cocaine'
gem 'rmagick'                   
gem 'carrierwave'               
gem 'remotipart'                
gem 'deep_cloneable', '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record' 
gem 'daemons'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem "jquery-migrate-rails", "~> 1.0.0"
gem 'ransack'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.2.3"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
group :development, :test do
  gem 'cheat'                   
  gem 'ruby-growl'
  gem 'letter_opener'           
  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.0"
  gem 'database_cleaner'        
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara', '2.0.1'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'mocha', :require => false
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
end
```